# finding a functional path through a graph with a twist

Tags: python, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I was wondering whats the best way to go about finding a path through a simple, undirected graph where the path must go through nodes that contain a specific attribute. The allowable gap between the nodes that contain the said attribute can be specified when calling the path finding function. (By gap I don't mean the edge, I mean the nodes that don't contain the attribute)

I was thinking a bfs/dfs approach but not sure how to incorporate checking to see if the attribute falls within the allowable distance.

Planning on developing this for my resume to demonstrate graph theory knowledge. Trying to develop in python as well.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to remove from the graph all nodes that do not possess the required attribute.  The trick would be to keep the links between the allowed nodes that was provided by the removed nodes.

So my approach would be to use Dijsktra to find the cheapest path between each pair of allowed nodes,  then create a new graph with the allowed nodes, where every pair of nodes has a link between them, costed by the cheapest path found by the previous Dijsktra runs.

Simple example:

node ( index, allowed )

```
1 yes
2 no
3 yes
4 yes
```

edges ( node, node, cost )

```
1 2 c1
2 3 c2
2 4 c3
```

becomes

```
1 3 c1+c2
1 4 c1+c3
3 4 c2+c3
```

To implement the maximum allowed "gap" the combined links in the new graph must be removed if they represent a gap greater than allowed.

Comment: If I wanted the graph to be unweighted, and just to find a path that works with the least amount of edges, how could I do that?

Comment: To find a path with the least amount of edges, set the weight of every edge to 1.